# How to perform negative testing in paypal express checkout button?

Tags: paypal

I want to perform negative testing with a PayPal checkout button

There is one method given in document for REST API. I tried to add header in my paypal render code as per documentation, but doesn't work.

```
paypal.Button.render({
        env: 'sandbox',
        client: {
           production: 'XXXXX',
          sandbox: 'XXXXX'
        },
        locale: 'en_US',
        style: {
          size: 'large',
          color: 'blue',
          shape: 'pill',
          tagline: false,
          label: 'paypal'
        },
        headers: {
          "PayPal-Mock-Response" : {"mock_application_codes": "INSTRUMENT_DECLINED"}
        },
        commit: true,
        payment: this.paypalPayment,
        onAuthorize: this.paypalAuthCallback
      }, '#paypal-button');
```

Comment: "didn't work" why not? what happened? why was that wrong?

Answer (score 0):

General REST API negative testing can only be done with a server-side integration, where your server communicates with the PayPal API directly, per https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/ , and your front-end UI calls corresponding routes on your server per https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

---

For some [generated Card #s](https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2FcreditCardGenerator%2F) (not all Card #s), you can trigger an INSTRUMENT_DECLINED by setting the shipping address to CCREJECT-REFUSED https://developer.paypal.com/docs/archive/express-checkout/ht-ec-fundingfailure10486/#test-your-integration

---

Whatever you do, update from the old checkout.js (in your code example) to the latest sdk.js ; the client-side demo is here: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client